# Using 'distinct' word throws error 'cannot create a row of size 8065 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 3 tables in which I have lots of data (rows and columns). I have to select all the column from all table based on some common column. So I did this total no of columns are more then 1300. Now When I select all data with keyword 'Distinct' (as per requirement) it throws error:

> Cannot create a row of size 8065 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060;

but when I remove keyword 'Distinct' the data is returned. But I can't remove distinct as I need to show distinct records only.

Comment: *"total no of columns are more then 1300"*: this is never a good reason to have so many columns in one table. Redesign your database, and normalize it.

Comment: Usually when you require `distinct`, it's because there is some issue with joins. Are you certain you're not joining more rows than you need to? Besides that, 1300 columns rings alarm bells

Comment: Are you 100% percent you need a DISTINCT keyword? 1300 columns and distinct is a row level operation. Either your schema has some problems or your query should be rewritten. It is almost certain, that there will be no identical *rows* when you have 1300 columns, if there are you have duplicates somewhere else, solve that first. As the others said, 1300 columns SHOULD ring a bell.

Comment: Redesign your database or your query (for example, `DISTINCT` the individual tables, then join them), or perform the operation outside SQL Server. The 8,060 row size limit is a hard limit -- if you hit it, there's no way to circumvent it other than actually reducing the size of your data. SQL Server already tries to mitigate the impact by storing variable length columns in an overflow area so actual rows can have more than 8 KB of data, so if you manage to hit this limit still you're definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME REBUILD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, distinct was really required. I come to know that **Distinct** is causing the problem. Thanks for the hints. I removed the DISTINCT word from sql query/procedure and fetch all records. Now I selected the distinct records at server side code behind file.